# How do you unlock Blackbeard in LEGO Pirates of the Caribbean?

Tags: lego-pirates-of-the-caribbean

I've completed the story mode of LEGO Pirates of the Caribbean, but when I go back in free play mode, there are a few things that can only be affected by Blackbeard's sword, but he doesn't appear to have been unlocked by completing story mode. How do you unlock Blackbeard, or get his sword?

Comment: How many Studs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [videogamesblogger.com](http://www.videogamesblogger.com/2011/05/11/lego-pirates-of-the-caribbean-characters-list-how-to-unlock-and-buy-secret-characters-guide.htm):

> Here’s a quick video explaining how to unlock characters including:
>
> - The location of Blackbeard*;
> - How to unlock Blackbeard*;
> - How to purchase characters;
> - How to create custom characters;

It looks like you do have to complete the game to have him show up, but after that you need to go across the bridge that's to the left of [the port-area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEkND.png) and kill him.

Comment: For some odd reason, Blackbeard is not there. I've completed the game and the bridge works on mine, but when I cross it he isn't there. Only the red hat that I unlocked.